# How to running JSP on remote computer

Tags: python, jsp, tomcat, scripting, python-requests

Assume there is a tomcat apache server on http://192.168.1.10:8443/sample.jsp which is print a result on the page.

How can we get that result in a script from command line or command line browsers like elinks from another computer?
No matter is this a bash script, php script or a python one.

I used python script with requests and re modules for fetching the page source, but there's no success!

Answer (score 0):

One option is

```
curl http://192.168.1.10:8443/sample.jsp > local_file_name.txt
```

Numerous others are available as well. Which one to choose it up to you, and the best option determines what you'd like to do with the result.

Comment: The result is nothing. I've tested tools like wget and elinks before, but no result yet. But when you run it from your windows client browser, it has some data.